# sql for all departments count employees who do not work on a project for that department

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I need to create a view that reports the department name and how many employees don't work on any projects controlled by that department.

I know how to create a view, an also have figured out ways to get the count of how many employees do work on projects for a department via joins, but cannot figure out how to get the number of employees that don't, paired with that department. This is general SQL and not tied to particular DBMS, so I probably need to avoid obscure SQL commands limited to a specific DBMS.

I have created a mock up of the parts of the schema I believe relevant to the problem here:

```
Create Table DEPARTMENT (Dname VARCHAR(30), Dnumber INTEGER primary key , Mgr_ssn INTEGER, Mgr_start_date Varchar(30));
INSERT INTO Department (Dname,Mgr_ssn,Mgr_start_date) values ('maths',1,'foo');
INSERT INTO Department (Dname,Mgr_ssn,Mgr_start_date) values ('physics',2,'foo');


Create Table PROJECT (Pname VARCHAR(30), Pnumber INTEGER primary key , Plocation varchar(10), Dnum INTEGER);
INSERT INTO PROJECT (Pname,Plocation,Dnum) values ('project','the moon',1);
INSERT INTO PROJECT (Pname,Plocation,Dnum) values ('project','the moon',1);
INSERT INTO PROJECT (Pname,Plocation,Dnum) values ('project','the moon',2);
INSERT INTO PROJECT (Pname,Plocation,Dnum) values ('project','the moon',2);
INSERT INTO PROJECT (Pname,Plocation,Dnum) values ('project','the moon',2);

Create Table EMPLOYEE (Fname VARCHAR(30), SSn INTEGER primary key);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Fname) VALUES ('rick');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Fname) VALUES ('rick');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Fname) VALUES ('rick');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Fname) VALUES ('rick');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Fname) VALUES ('rick');

Create Table WORKS_ON (Essn INTEGER,Pno INTEGER, primary key(Essn,Pno));
INSERT INTO WORKS_ON VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO WORKS_ON VALUES(2,4);
INSERT INTO WORKS_ON VALUES(3,3);
INSERT INTO WORKS_ON VALUES(4,4);
INSERT INTO WORKS_ON VALUES(4,3);
INSERT INTO WORKS_ON VALUES(4,2);
```

While this is an academic exercise, this is not an assignment, and so if I don't get this done, or otherwise get help with a solution, i'll never know how to tackle these types of queries.

The very first thing I had tried was getting a count  of every employee that exists, then trying to subtract the count of every employee who works on projects for each department, but I couldn't get the arithmetic to work on all the rows. I have been unable to get other solutions using SET Minus and sub queries working.

Edit: what I had to get counts of employees working on projects for each department:

```
SELECT Dnumber, count(*) num_employees_on_projects FROM department d
INNER JOIN PROJECT p on d.Dnumber = p.Dnum
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON w on w.Pno = p.Pnumber 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e on e.Ssn = w.essn
group by Dnumber
```

Comment: Did you try using the "NOT" keyword?

Comment: To be ANSI SQL compliant and portable, you need to define default values for the primary keys, or insert their values explicitly.

Comment: a NOT keyword cannot be used that simply, since getting the count of employees is done by joining department to project and to works_on to get a list of records with department numbers and ssns of employees.

Comment: At least your *mock up*  should be valid SQL, currently those inserts will be fail.

Comment: @dnoeth I had sqlfiddle set to sqlite (changed from mySQL 5.7 which didn't allow sub queries in views), in which integer primary keys are automatically set and incremented. adding AUTO_INCREMENT to those inserts also work fine in mySQL.

Comment: Now add your existing query to get the count per department, then it's easy to modify it :-)

Comment: I've now done this, but I can't for the life of me see an easy modification (though I thought there would be when I first tried).

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to outer joins to include non-matching rows. And then you count a column from the right most table (`WORKS_ON`) which is known to be NOT NULL, easiest one is the join column:

```
SELECT Dnumber,
   count(*) as all_employees,
   count(w.Pno) as employees_on_projects,
   count(*) - count(w.Pno) as employees_without_project
FROM department d
LEFT JOIN PROJECT p on d.Dnumber = p.Dnum
LEFT JOIN WORKS_ON w on w.Pno = p.Pnumber 
-- LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE e on e.Ssn = w.essn -- not needed
group by Dnumber;
```

Edit:

To relate the data per department to the overall count of employees you might add a Scalar Subquery:

```
SELECT Dnumber,
   count(w.Pno) as employees_on_projects,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM EMPLOYEE) -- all employees
    - count(w.Pno) as employees_without_project
FROM department d
LEFT JOIN PROJECT p on d.Dnumber = p.Dnum
LEFT JOIN WORKS_ON w on w.Pno = p.Pnumber 
group by Dnumber;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fca0c/1)

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, this actually gives me a perspective on another way to interpret the question and how I would achieve that. However, what I was originally aiming to do was subtract the amount of employees on a project from the total global number of employees, and still can't figure this out.

Comment: for some reason when I add another department, I get these results, when I would be expecting 0 employees and 6 employees not on the project http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f59332/2

Comment: @tavtavtav: And what's your expected result?

Comment: As there are 6 total employees, then those departments with 4 working on projects for that department, should have the number 2 returned.

Comment: @tavtavtav: Now I see. As you want to get data per department the easiest way is to add a Scalar Subquery returning the count of employees. I'll modify my answer

Comment: This gives the expected results, thank you very much for this approach.